# Pass CSS value with ngStyle

Tags: css, angular

I've got a service sending a value, which I need it to be passed to the CSS file so I can control how much a meter gauge moves.
The value is between 0 and 0.5, and changes the

```
transform:rotate( {NUMBER} turn)
```

On classes dynamically chosen with a previous nGclass.

Example: If my var is 0.5, I need the resulting CSS code to be

```
transform:rotate(.5turn)
```

How can I manage this?

I've tried

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform:rotate(.5turn)': dashService.variable}"
```

And other variations of the same idea but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interpolation syntax:

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate(' + dashService.variable + 'turn)': }"
```

Comment: Thank you a LOT! I just needed to add 'turn' at the end, resulting in:

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate(' + dashService.variable + 'turn)' }"
```

But it worked flawlessly!! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + this.myApp.urlImagen + ')'}"
```

I have used this to add style to an element before. Make any changes and It'll be fine :)

Comment: This is what Im trying to do, but Im having trouble finding the right syntax for transform: rotate(X turn)

Comment: @dizzydizzy replace "url(" by "rotate(" and this.myApp.urlImagen for your value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[style.transform]="'rotate(' + (dashService.variable) + 'deg)'"
```